# Full VB in the original VAE paper

Tags: inference, autoencoders

I've few doubts in the original [VAE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114) paper,

[image: Equation1]

Doubt1: Equation 1 says use equality, however, it seems that Equation-1 and Equation-2 combined imply

$logp_\theta(x^{(i)}) = E_{q_\phi(z|x)}[log(\frac{p_\theta(z)p_\theta(x^{(i)}|z)}{p_\theta(z|x^{(i)})})]$
, where the expectation is wrt $q_\phi$, rather than $p_\theta$. Moreover, the RHS seems to be expected value of $log p(x)$. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Doubt2: Full VB has been described in the appendix, where variational inference is done on network parameters $\theta$ as well as latents $z$. They have called $q_\phi(\theta)$ as the approximate posterior. Shouldn't posterior be conditioned on the data X.

Comment: Hi and welcome! These should really be posted as two separate questions. Do you mind making that change, so you can get better answers?

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: Sure, that I'll do. It's pretty cool, I didn't knew about this. Thanks.